# Run Highcharts on Server side code to add to Word document

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am using Highcharts on an ASP.Net MVC Project.
All works great on client side/js however I have a requirement to create a word document via the project that includes one of these charts you can see on screen.

I currently use Novacode's docx library to create/modify word files and this works great. I can add images easily and if necessary I can create the basic looking charts with .Nets charting library but I'd prefer to use the Highcharts ones.

Does anyone know how via a Controller (i.e. server side) I can create a Highcharts chart or get the image for one to use in the document. The only examples I can find still require some level of JS to accomplish it.

Comment: Are you looking for the Word document to have live data from your Highcharts charts? If you simply want an image or snapshot of the data, you can use the native exporting feature, save the chart as a JPEG, PNG, or SVG, and import that into your Word document.

Comment: Just the image to include in the document. Can you use the native exporting server side though? The chart needs to be created as part of the document creation on the Controller. As I say without js being involved.

Comment: Highcharts has information on setting up your own export server: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server. I'd start here to see whether this could work with your controller.

Comment: I don't want to setup another server to do this. I was hoping I could post directly to export.highcharts.com but can't find a good example of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this myself in the end using the following:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://export.highcharts.com");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("", content).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(pathname, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            response.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ContinueWith(
               (copyTask) =>
               {
                   fileStream.Close();
               });
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to poste data. Status code:{response.StatusCode}");
        }
```

The json for it I constructed via the options here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Apologies for the crude example which I will obviously modify and clean up my end but wanted to give the answer to this should anyone else find it useful.